# Will this power strip work on 230V 50Hz?

Tags: power

I would like to share a universal socket power strip that has 3 universal sockets and 6 USB ports. This is the link: [https://www.amazon.com/3-Outlet-Protector-Charging-Extension-Cord-White/dp/B07F3WV6KB/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F3WV6KB) (BAVIN 3-Outlet "Surge Protector" Power Strip with USB Charging 6 Ports 5.4A/27W, 5Ft Heavy Duty Extension Cord-White)

I want to know whether the power strip is multi-voltage or single voltage.

This is what is written on the back of the power strip: BAVIN PC588 ANTI-STATIC POWER SOCKET Input: AC100-240V, 50-60Hz 350mA OUTPUT:DC 5V-5.4A(MAX) 30W.

I am from the US, which uses 120V at 60Hz. I will be travelling to Europe, which uses 230V at 50Hz. Will the power strip work (auto switch to 230V 50Hz) or will I need a voltage transformer?

Comment: What are you going to be using it for?

Comment: Note the comments on that listing. If you want USB charging to use in Europe there are other, listed, alternatives. Not cheap ungrounded stuff like this.

Comment: The description says "compatible with outlets in North America, United Kingdom..." which supply 120v at 60Hz and about 230v at 50 Hz respectively. You say it is labelled "AC100-240V, 50-60Hz" so what's the problem? Apart from being sold out :)

Comment: echoing what Midalvo has already asked. It really depends on what you want to plug into it.

Comment: @JonCuster: I only use the power strip to power lights with a timer.

Comment: @BavinNotn: again that depends on the details: what timing device and what lights ? Most lightbulbs are generally NOT dual voltage. However LED lightstrips powered with power brick often are.

Comment: @BavinNotn - which might be OK (and might not depending on construction) until somebody else plugs something else in. This thing is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: @JonCuster How is this an accident waiting to happen? If I am not using lights with a timer, I only use it to charge my phones/iPads/laptops (without using the USB ports).

Comment: In the UK, a plug contains a fuse (as apposed to elsewhere where a fusebox exists). If your power socket has no proper fused UK plug and something goes wrong (if a device doesn't switch properly to 230W, remaing at 110W, it will return the 120W back to the system causing an overload) then the whole house could be effected instead of only rooms otherwise covered by a fusebox. In a large hotel, there may be some who are not amused.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I checked other universal power strips at this link: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=universal+power+strip&crid=1HRO1VOH9C93G&sprefix=universal+power+strip%2Caps%2C150&ref=nb_sb_noss_1. It looks like all the universal power strips (like this one) are rated for a maximum of 250V 10A 2500W. However, all the universal power strips are uncertified.

Comment: Look for the wording contained in this sample: [Amazon.com: Anker Power Strip Surge Protector (2100J), 12 Outlets with 2 USB A and 1 USB C Port for Multiple Devices, 5ft Extension Cord, 20W Power Delivery Charging for Home, Office, Dorm Essential, TUV Listed : Electronics](https://www.amazon.com/Anker-Protector-Multiple-Extension-Essential/dp/B09SG2Q23M?th=1) *8-Point Safety System: Combines **surge protection**, fire resistance, **overload protection**, temperature control, and more to protect you and your devices.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am worried about the universal power strips. It looks like all the universal power strips are rated for a maximum voltage of 250V. https://www.amazon.com/s?k=universal+power+strip&crid=1HRO1VOH9C93G&sprefix=universal+power+strip%2Caps%2C150&ref=nb_sb_noss_1

Comment: The standard in Europe is now 230V. Many (older) devices support the range 220-240V 50/60Hz. So a max of 250V is fine. I have just ordered a TV with 100-240V~50/60Hz. Important is that it should turn itsself off if more than 3.680 W is being extracted at once.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Most universal power strips have a maximum rating of 250V 10A 2500W. I am worried that the manufacturer might be faking the rating (claiming that it is multi-voltage). Amazon doesn't have any quality control (QC) check. They allow any product to be sold regardless of certification status. There are no pictures on the reviews of the product. I don't know if any universal power strips have circuit breakers/fuses.

Comment: When in the UK, you will need a US/UK plug adapter. That adapter should have a fuse (the cheap ones often don't). If the offer doesn't state that explicitly: **don't buy it**. A US/European plug adapter does not require a fuse. (can a UK reader confirm this? Its been a long time since I have deal with the UK specifics)

Comment: @BavinNotn, please do not change the country/area you intent to travel once you have answers that are specific for your travel location.

Answer (score 7):

The powerstrip will work in Europe, including the UK.
But it will give out the power that comes in.

So if you plug it into the socket in Europe it will get 230 volt in and it will give out 230 volt, frying anything you plug into it which is made for the American 120 volt.

The USB ports will give out the normal USB power, no problems there.

As indicated in a comment on the question it will be easier to bring a USB charger, there are some around with 4 or even more ports with universal plugs or series of plug which can be exchanged.

Comment: (+1) In the amazon page *About this item: ... **Note**: Products with electrical plugs are designed for use in the US. Outlets and voltage differ internationally and this product may require an adapter or converter for use in your destination. Please check compatibility before purchasing.*

Comment: The USB ports are rated for 5.4A. What will happen if I plug in iPad (2.4A), phone (1A), power bank (2A), and a Bluetooth speaker (0.5A)? I don't know if the power strip has any overload/overcurrent protection. I only want universal power strips, not local ones.

Comment: **each** USB port supports upto 5.4A. 2.4+1+2+0.5= **5.9A**. With 230V each wall plug can support up to 3680W (or 16A=3680W/230V) **at once**. With 5.9A you are using 1357W (5.9A\*230V) out of the allowed 3680W with 230V.

Comment: @MarkJohnson i guess you meant 5.9A*5V, since that's usually the voltage of a USB port.

Comment: @dunni No. I have understood the OP values as being the values of the individual 4 USB ports, which taken togeather is 5.9A. The power source (wall plug connected to the powerstrip) can service up to 16A with 230V at the same time. A save/secure powerstrip should shutdown (overload protection) if the extracted amount nears the maximum amount (16A/3680W with 230V) allowed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The power strip is rated for 10A, not 16A.

Comment: @dunni The power strip has 6 USB ports.

Comment: The power strip cannot be opened if anything fails.

Comment: I am from the US, which uses 120V at 60Hz. It looks like the power strip is rated for 1250W (125V 10A).

Comment: @MarkJohnson i was referring to the following sentence in your comment: `With 5.9A you are using 1357W (5.9A*230V) out of the allowed 3680W with 230V`. Those 4 devices will pull 5.9A at 5 V, so the total load on the powerstrip will be 30 W (+ any loss because of efficiency), not 1357W.

Comment: @dunni A USB will pull what it actually needs (it **does not** pull the maximum possible all the time). I have 3 Android devices and a lamp (all on while writing this) connected to a [Voltcraft Sem6500](https://www.amazon.de/-/de/VOLTCRAFT-SEM6500-Energy-Function-Forecast/dp/B09NFM5RD3/) that measures the energy being used. It presently fluctuates between 0.08A and 0.09A (11/12W).

Comment: Note that plugging in European plugs in this stip will result in the safety earth being interrupted, which is a safety hazard.

Comment: And FWIW, it's only the USB part that actually cares what the voltage and frequency is. Plain old power strips will put out whatever - 12 volts, 120 volts, 50Hz, 60Hz, 600 Hz, 0 Hz (DC)... they don't care because they are just wires. Often they are rated for 600 volts although I wouldn't count on it. And usually rated for 10 or 15 or 20 amps maximum. I *have* plugged one into an Arduino input before, for a very unusual purpose.

Answer (score 2):

That power strip is just a power strip, and does not contain any magical voltage conversion tech (except USB, of course).  This is easily confirmed by contemplating: "how does it know which voltage I want?" You get the same voltage out as in, and it simply exists as a means to physically connect loads which already accept the voltage it's plugged into.

So how to work with international power?

Your first strategy should be "do not haul electrical equipment across oceans".  It takes several times the item's weight in CO2, and they have hair dryers in France. Honest.

For extraordinarily valuable equipment, like computers and electronics, grab a magnifying glass and look closely at the nameplate on the device or its power supply.  I bet it says something like 100-240V or 90-264V... this is typical of switching power supplies that are able to accept any voltage in that range.  These do not need voltage conversion - don't bother.

Of what remains, it generally falls into two categories: very low power things like toothbrushes, and very high power things like hair dryers.  These require different strategies.

For the low power items (under 25 watts), the best bet is an actual, literal transformer, as this will be sanely priced.  These will be fixed voltage.  Get one that has your destination country's plug and your country's socket, and is approved by local standards bodies. (CE is unreliable by mail).

For high power resistance heat appliance like coffee makers *didn't I say don't bring those?* they make inexpensive electronic chopper converters that use triacs to chop up the 230V sine-wave - it's not great, but it will work with a resistive heat appliance.

If the above don't fit, your last resort is a large, costly and very heavy large transformer. However this will be the wrong frequency, and loads that depend on AC frequency to run at the correct speed will not like it. (Record turntable, motor, clock etc.) Carrying one of those in baggage is even more wasteful than hauling the appliance itself.  Just buy or rent an equivalent appliance domestically when you arrive.

Well if frequency is critical, the "Hail Mary" play is an *online double-conversion* UPS, but we're really over the moon on cost and weight at this point.

Comment: I don't know if they sell them on your side of the pond, but here in the UK you can buy "travel hairdriers" with a voltage selector switch.